# A script to parse internet audio stream from Music.app and save it in a text file

Tags: applescript, bash, automation, ventura, music.app

I listen to the Internet radio in my Music.app on macOS Ventura and I would like a script that could parse the artist and the song name and paste it as a new line in a text file in the background every time the song changes. How is it possible?

[image: Internet audio stream artist and song]

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a free scriptwriting service. You will need to show us what research you have done so far & where you are stuck. Include examples of your work so far. See [How do I ask a good question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Ask Different question checklist](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3387/ask-different-question-checklist)

Comment: To narrow the research area: AppleScript is the way to go here.

Comment: @Dmitry, [this](https://github.com/cashiecoder/musicstream) is a project I made that does this.

Comment: (sorry) trying to delete my comment